# Dynamic REST API call from Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 GET API methods:

1. List all persons ids  /person
2. Display all the details of a specific person /person/{id}

Is there a way to trigger the call to the person/{id} method -with the selected id- when a row is clicked or a value is selected in a slicer to retrieve the specific person data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Web.Contents connector doesn't support DirectQuery, so it can only be used during Dataset refresh.